# Parse timestamp with a.m./p.m

Tags: r, timestamp, strptime

I have a file that formats time stamps like `25/03/2011 9:15:00 p.m.`

How can I parse this text to a Date-Time class with either [`strptime`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/strptime.html) or [`as.POSIXct`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/as.POSIXlt.html)?

Here is what almost works:

```
> as.POSIXct("25/03/2011 9:15:00", format="%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S", tz="UTC")
[1] "2011-03-25 09:15:00 UTC"
```

Here is what is not working, but I'd like to have working:

```
> as.POSIXct("25/03/2011 9:15:00 p.m.", format="%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz="UTC")
[1] NA
```

I'm using R version 2.13.2 (2011-09-30) on MS Windows. My working locale is "C":

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
```

Comment: `?strptime` says that `%p` is "AM/PM indicator in the locale". http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/time-put.html says in the C locale it is AM/PM, so I think you'll have to `sub("a.m","AM",...)` and `sub("p.m.","PM",...)` first.  (There's probably a slick regular expression that would do it all in one go.)

Comment: @BenBolker: I got your slick regular expression right here... :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It appears the AM/PM indicator can't include punctuation.  Try it after removing the punctuation:

```
td <- "25/03/2011 9:15:00 p.m."
tdClean <- gsub("(.)\\.?[Mm]\\.?","\\1m",td)
as.POSIXct(tdClean, format="%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz="UTC")
# [1] "2011-03-25 21:15:00 UTC"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this, as another option you can use `stringr` package.

```
library(stringr)
data$date2 <- str_sub(data$date, end = -4) 
# this removes the punctuation but holds onto the A/P values
data$date2 <- str_c(data$date2, 'm') 
# adds the required m
```