# Parsing time stamps - AM/PM not recognized

Tags: r, datetime, timestamp, posixct

I'm trying to convert some timestamps (character) to a `POSIXct` object:

```
> u <- "December 05, 2017 1:00 PM"
```

I'm using `as.POSIXct` as below:

```
> as.POSIXct(u, format = "%B %d, %Y %H:%M %p", tz = "UTC")
[1] "2017-12-05 01:00:00 UTC"
```

I would expect the output to show `13` for the hour instead of `01`:

```
"2017-12-05 13:00:00 UTC"
```

I've seen the question posted here: [Parse timestamp with a.m./p.m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883806/parse-timestamp-with-a-m-p-m) but I seem to have the correct input and format string (with `%p`).

`as.POSIXct` appears to completely ignore the AM/PM part of the string and therefore the AM timestamps work fine but the PM stamps lag by 12 hours. Here's some more data to illustrate this:

```
> sample_tstamps
 [1] "December 05, 2017 8:00 AM"  "December 05, 2017 9:00 AM"  "December 05, 2017 10:00 AM" "December 05, 2017 11:00 AM"
 [5] "December 05, 2017 12:00 PM" "December 05, 2017 1:00 PM"  "December 05, 2017 2:00 PM"  "December 05, 2017 3:00 PM" 
 [9] "December 05, 2017 4:00 PM"  "December 05, 2017 5:00 PM" 
> as.POSIXct(sample_tstamps, format = "%B %d, %Y %H:%M %p", tz = "UTC")
 [1] "2017-12-05 08:00:00 UTC" "2017-12-05 09:00:00 UTC" "2017-12-05 10:00:00 UTC" "2017-12-05 11:00:00 UTC"
 [5] "2017-12-05 12:00:00 UTC" "2017-12-05 01:00:00 UTC" "2017-12-05 02:00:00 UTC" "2017-12-05 03:00:00 UTC"
 [9] "2017-12-05 04:00:00 UTC" "2017-12-05 05:00:00 UTC"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need `%I` instead of `%H`

```
as.POSIXct(u, format = "%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p", tz = "UTC")
#[1] "2017-12-05 13:00:00 UTC"
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work and I'll update the code. I'm surprised though - I've always used `%H` in the past (see https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html) without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Using the R-package `lubridate`:

```
u <- "December 05, 2017 1:00 PM"
lubridate::mdy_hm(u)
#[1] "2017-12-05 13:00:00 UTC"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to use this but I don't want to use any external packages for this specific problem.